# sql - sum,average values in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
DATE    TIME    ITEM    PRICE
01-01-2011  0   Gold    22000
01-01-2011  1   Gold    23000
01-01-2011  2   Gold    22000
01-01-2011  3   Gold    21000
01-01-2011  4   Gold    24000
01-01-2011  5   Gold    19000
01-01-2011  6   Gold    18000
01-01-2011  7   Gold    17000
01-01-2011  8   Gold    16000
01-01-2011  9   Gold    30000
02-01-2011  0   Gold    22000
02-01-2011  1   Gold    15000
02-01-2011  2   Gold    28000
02-01-2011  3   Gold    31000
02-01-2011  4   Gold    19000
02-01-2011  5   Gold    22000
02-01-2011  6   Gold    23000
02-01-2011  7   Gold    25000
02-01-2011  8   Gold    26000
02-01-2011  9   Gold    27000
```

I want to have an output as:

```
DATE        ITEM    TOT      AVG    MAX     TIME_MAX MIN    TIME_MIN
01-01-2011  GOLD    21200   2120    30000   9        16000  8
02-01-2011  GOLD    23800   2380    31000   3        15000  1
```

where:

- DATE - date from the table
- ITEM - item from the table
- TOT - sum of price in a day
- AVG - average of price in a day
- MAX - maximum price in a day
- TIME_MAX - time at which the price was maximum in a day
- MIN - minimum price in a day
- TIME_MIN - time at which price was minimum in a day

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using and the version , eg. SQL Server 2016, Oracle 11g

Comment: While it is interesting what table you have and what output you want (thanks for telling the story), is there any question you have? Any SQL you tried and have issues with?

Comment: Also please state what you have tried.

Comment: what if more rows have maximum/minimum in that day?

Comment: Stackoverflow is NOT a free coding service. if you have troubles with a query, we will help you. but we won't do your work!

Comment: Check out `GROUP BY`, and the aggregate functions `SUM()`, `AVG()`, `MAX()` and `MIN()`.

Comment: I have tried the following code:                                                              select date,item,time,max(price),min(price),sum(price) from table t group by date,item, time                                                                                                  
This query is giving me the output per hour wise.

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This query.

```
SELECT 
DATE,ITEM,SUM(PRICE) AS TOT,
AVG(PRICE) AS AVG,
MAX(PRICE) AS MAX,
MAX(TIME) AS TIME_MAX,
MIN(PRICE) AS MIN,
MIN(TIME) AS TIME_MIN
FROM T
GROUP BY DATES,ITEM;
```

Since you do not need Time in your result, its not needed to include it in the `SELECT` statement of `GROUP BY` statement.